# Prove or refute - FO logic and structures

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma$ be a signature with a constant symbol $c$ and let $\Phi \in FO[\sigma]$ and $\psi(x) \in FO[\sigma]$. Prove or refute the following statements:
>
> $(i)$ If $\Phi \models \forall x \psi(x)$, then $\Phi \models \psi(c)$.
>
> $(ii)$ If $\Phi \models \exists x \psi(x)$, then $\Phi \models \psi(c)$.
>
> $(iii)$ If $\Phi \models x \neq x$ , then $\Phi \models x = x$.
>
> $(iv)$ $\exists x \psi(x) \models \exists x (\psi(x) \land x \neq c)$.

My attempt:

$(i)$ is correct, since we're quantifying over all the values of the free variable $x$ in the structure's universe and the constant $c$ has to come from the same universe, so at some point $x$ has to be equal to $c$.

$(ii)$ is incorrect, because we don't know anything about $c$. (Question: Since we don't know what our universe is, how can we give a counterexample here?)

$(iii)$ is correct, since $x \neq x$ is always false, the statement $\Phi \models x \neq x$ is also false, making the implication $\Phi \models x \neq x \rightarrow \Phi \models x = x$ true.

$(iv)$ is incorrect, because $c$ can be the only $x$ for which $\psi(x)$ is true.

---

I'm very sceptical of my answers, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m convinced by what you did.

Regarding point (ii). To find a counterexample, we just have to find a model in which $\Phi$ and $\exists x \psi(x)$ hold but $\psi(c)$ doesn’t.

For this take $M=\{1,2\}$, $\Phi \equiv c=c$, $\psi(x) \equiv x=1 \wedge \neg x=2$ and interpret $c $ as $2$.